# How to add more than one SQL statement/Query String on 1 DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I currently have the following statement with QueryString set to ProductCategory on my ListView control:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductCategory = ?)
```

I would like to add this statement and query string on the same DataSource to allow query string for ProductModel as well, how can I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductModel = ?)
```

ListVIew

```
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView" GroupItemCount="3" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div style="height: 966px;">
        <div style="width: 771px;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder" />
        <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="dpMyDatePager" PageSize="9"
 PagedControlID="listView">
<Fields>
    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True"
     ShowFirstPageButton="True" />
     <asp:NumericPagerField />
</Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
        </div>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
<div class="productItem">
    <div>
        <img src='<%# Eval("ProductUrl") %>' >
    </div>
    <div class="catalog-price">
    <br />    
            <%# Eval("ProductBrand") %>
            <%# Eval("ProductModel") %></div>

    <div class="catalog-price2">
        <b>
        Our Price: S$<%# Eval("NormalPrice") %></div>
        </b><br />
    <div class="cell1">
        Add to cart</div>
    <div class="cell2">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HypViewDetails" style="text-decoration:none"      NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ProductId", "ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0}")%>'
 runat="server">View Details</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <div class="itemSeparator">
        </div>
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
        <div class="groupSeparator">
        </div>
    </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/TabStoreDB.mdb" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductCategory = ?) OR    (ProductBrand = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="ProductCategory" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="?" QueryStringField="ProductBrand" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am totally not understanding your problem. You can just add `AND/OR` to you `WHERE` clause

`OR WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE (ProductCategory = ?)
OR (ProductModel = ?)
```

`AND WHERE` Clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE (ProductCategory = ?)
AND (ProductModel = ?)
```

Based on your edit you have both query parameters are ? - they each need to have a specific name

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductCategory = @ProductCategory) OR    (ProductBrand = @ProductBrand)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductCategory" QueryStringField="ProductCategory" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductBrand" QueryStringField="ProductBrand" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

If you are unsure of how to use the parameters, I suggest the following reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx

Comment: Hi, I've tried the above statement but nothing appears on my ListView control when i try to access a productmodel eg. Products.aspx?ProductModel=Acer

Comment: I think you need to provide some more details about what you are trying to do. Do you want to search by ProductCategory OR ProductModel?

Comment: I would like it to be able to be searched by either ProductCategory or ProductModel. For instance when Products.aspx?ProductCategory=Accessories is entered, ListView will display all accessories and when Products.aspx?ProductModel=Acer is entered, ListView will display all products with the model 'Acer'

Comment: @aurelio -- which of the two statements above did you try?  The top one (with the OR) should work *at least* as well as your original query did...

Comment: @kuru kuru I've tried both of the statements but didn't worked :/

Comment: @aurelio if you run the OR query on its own not from the ListView does it work?

Comment: If i run only one statement, eg. SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductCategory = ?) The ListView can do the ProductCategory query with no problems. What could be the problem? :/

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code for your ListView?

Comment: You need to change your parameter names so they are not the same.  Right now they are both ? marks

Comment: @bluefeet i've tried your solution but it still doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: from what I can see it appears that this code should be working.  I must be missing something.

Comment: @bluefeet Hmm is the link for query still the same? Eg. ?ProductBrand=

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for the links. I pretty much have no more ideas what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You gave both parameters the same name.  You need to be specfic -- try this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (ProductCategory = @cat) OR    (ProductBrand = @brand)">
```

And then this:

```
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="cat" QueryStringField="ProductCategory" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="brand" QueryStringField="ProductBrand" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: I've tried your recommendation, but ListView still doesn't show anything. Weird.

Comment: Sorry -- not sure what else to suggest.  My @ notation was from sql-server -- you might check that against Access, to see if it needs to be something else.

Comment: No problems, Thanks for trying to help. Appreciate it :)